# Where & how can I see IIS7 log entries for a specific web site?

Tags: iis-7, logging

All IIS7 is telling me is a folder (i.e. C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles) which contains a couple of subfolders. 
How can I tell which subfolder/file I should look at?
What is the logic behind this folder/file structure?

BTW. A side question: Does MS provide any log viewer with a nice UI?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you click on the Web Sites node in IIS Manager, there is a site Id.  The log path will be c:\inetpub\logs\logfiles\w3svc{siteid}, or msftp{siteid} for ftp. (by default)

MS doesn't have a log viewer UI at this time but I'm sure there are plenty of them out there.  MS has 'Log Parser' which rocks, but it's not a UI, it's just very powerful.

Answer (score 3):

In IIS Manager, click on Sites folder. You will see the **ID** (identity) of the website. Default Web Site is by default 1.
Click on the **Web Site** (Default Web Site) you want to see the log. In the Features View double click on Logging icon. There you can see which directory has the logs. You will see folders like W3SVC1 where 1 is the identity of the website.
There is no good logviewer UI from Microsoft, but if you open the same in Excel it helps Filtering your data much better.
Hope this helps.
Vivek