# Windows server log of hits?

Tags: windows

I'm trying to find the IP address of somebody that was browsing a website on our windows server at a specific time. Is it possible to find this out from some sort of log? If so, where would I find it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

http://indihiang.codeplex.com/  IIS Log Parser and very good to analyse logs / traffic
If you are using IIS and have logging on, you can find the logs at `C:\inetpub\logs`

http://forums.iis.net/t/1144488.aspx
[Where & how can I see IIS7 log entries for a specific web site?](https://serverfault.com/questions/91673/where-how-can-i-see-iis7-log-entries-for-a-specific-web-site)

Above links might help
Hope that Helps

Comment: Just open the IIS logs in a good text editor, and look for access at that time. Depending on the load on the server, it might be hard to find a single hit.