# Subdomain on a separate server (Windows/IIS) won't load default web site?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, subdomain

I've got a domain hosted under godaddy.com. I set it up so that `subdomain.mysite.com` points to a different server which uses Windows/IIS (say for example ip 1.1.1.1). When I go to the subdomain I get no errors, but no webpage loads.

In IIS under the default website I added a bindings for `subdomain.mysite.com` with the ip of `1.1.1.1`, but still nothing loads, just a totally blank page. In the developer window on Chrome on the Network tab there are no HTTP errors.

I know for sure the subdomain host is working correctly because when I ping my subdomain, the correct IP shows.

What am I missing to get this working? Is there something to change in the DNS? Right now in the DNS manager, there are no zones for anything.

Comment: Does it work when the bindings are 0.0.0.0? What do your logs say?

Comment: @Somantra No it doesn't work when bindings are 0.0.0.0. Which logs should I be looking at in the Event Manager? I can't find anything that would indicate what's going on.

Comment: The System Log (Look for W3SVC or ASP.NET and similar errors) and W3SVC Logs (Confirm HTTP Request/Response). You may want to try and view a simple plain html page and see if that loads vs .ASPX or whatever. Look here to find the W3SVC logs: http://serverfault.com/questions/91673/where-how-can-i-see-iis7-log-entries-for-a-specific-web-site

Comment: @Somantra The logs folder is empty. All it has is the wmsvc folder in it, but that is also empty. I am just trying to load a plain HTML page. It's just index.html with standard boilerplate plus a paragraph that has the text "Test" in it, but none of that loads.

Comment: Make sure you have HTTP logging enabled too: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754631(v=ws.10).aspx . If it wasn't enabled, make some more requests and then view the log again.

Comment: And if logging is enabled and the logs are still empty, verify the permissions of the W3SVC service to the location of the web site directory.

Comment: This guy has the right idea, except don't run in production as admin: http://obligious.blogspot.com/2011/12/iis-returns-blank-page.html

Comment: @Somantra I am not sure, logging wasn't even installed first (The server came barebones setup), after installing health and diagnostics services and checking the logs, everything appears fine. All attempts to hit "/" for the website are having status codes of 200 0 0 93 where only the last number changes. I also tried the permission thing in your last link, still a blank page though =(.

Comment: Gah I figured it out, it REALLY was barebones setup, none of the services were installed, including static content, http logging. Pretty much everything. Once I installed all that stuff (specifically static content) it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well I just got the server and it was barebones minimum setup. As such the majority of IIS role services were not installed. Once I installed Static Content (and a plethora of others), it worked!