# Individual webconfigs for subdomains in IIS7

Tags: iis-7, rewrite

We are currently running one domain with many subdomains for individual clients. These clients all have their own wishes for rewriting rules, and we would like to seperate these rules for each client's subdomain. If possible, we would like to seperate the web.configs.

Is there an easy way to do this in IIS7?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where & how can I see IIS7 log entries for a specific web site?](http://serverfault.com/questions/91673/where-how-can-i-see-iis7-log-entries-for-a-specific-web-site)

Comment: No not at all - this has nothing to do with logfiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are many ways to accomplish this (and likely opinions to go along with each) but I would do one of the two following:

**Separate the application into various websites within IIS**

- Use separate folders with unique web.config files
- Use separate application pools so each can be restarted without
  affecting any other sites

**Use 3rd Party Applications like Helicon Isapi Rewrite version 3**

- This software is great, used both version2 and three
- http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/

If you have under 20 subdomains, I would go with the first option. Pros: free, Cons: more administration. But you still have better control over the application if the application pools are split up. This way if one is misfiring for some reason, you can restart that one without affecting the others.

Helicon makes a good product. We use both solutions in our environment.

Mike

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We already have Helicon Ape installed on our IIS, and I was wondering if we could keep it to that without having to buy Helicon Isapi Rewrite. We basicly want seperate htaccess files then for each client, and they shouldn't be able to affect each other.

Comment: Is it possible to separate the application into various websites (for each subdomain)? That way you can use native IIS 7.0 / code rewrites instead of buying a bunch of ISAPI Rewrite licenses. I think this might be your only option to avoid the cost of buying more licenses.

Comment: We would like to avoid that option as much as possible, as we have a lot of clients.

Comment: Also it would be difficult to set up in the way we have our application, as the application itself is a general root application, and individual resources are allocated to clients' subdomains as folders. That's also why we would love to have a seperate htaccess or webconfig for every client without using seperate folders, as the individual resources folder don't actually contain anything related to the application, just things like pictures etc.

Comment: Could you make a relative path to htaccess files in Helicon Ape?

Comment: you can create junction points that might do what you are looking for. It's sort of like the Linux equivalent of ln -s: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-CA/sysinternals/bb896768.aspx

Comment: I don't see how that would really help, could you explain more what you're thinking of? Our clients do not have a seperate folder that contains webpages. If you mean put htaccess files in folders and then write symbolic links back to the root dir, would it really ever load that htaccess file?

Comment: Let me formulate myself better, basicly, a client does not have an actual path to his subdomain; there's no folder, everything is handled by our ColdFusion application. We simply would like to have url rewrites in different files for each client, without affecting anyone's elses and keeping an organised structure.

Comment: I have a better understanding of the issue now. But unfortunately, I don't think it's possible. You can definitely set up custom rewrites in the main .htaccess file for each client, or in a separate site in its own folder using web.config, but I do not believe it's possible to split up sections of the .htaccess (with custom access) for each customer's site. It's either all in the one file, or multiple files in multiple directories. Why don't you add comments to the one .htaccess for oganization? Or does it have to be accessed by the customers themselves?